# Path to gpt.ini missing

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy, replication

I am seeing the 1030 and 1058 errors for a remote Windows Server 2003 domain controller.  Specifically the 1058 error says:

```
> Event Type:   Error Event Source: Userenv Event Category: None Event
> ID:   1058 Date:      26/02/2013 Time:        14:05:43 User:      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
> Computer: REMOTE_SERVER Description: Windows cannot access the file
> gpt.ini for GPO
> cn={2B8907CD-E618-4BF5-8A49-FC92F8D85AE5},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=caid,DC=local.
> The file must be present at the location
> <\\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies\{2B8907CD-E618-4BF5-8A49-FC92F8D85AE5}\gpt.ini>.
> (The system cannot find the path specified. ). Group Policy processing
> aborted.
```

I can navigate to \domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\policies fine, but there is no folder in there with the GUID specified.  There are other folders present.

If I look for this folder on one of our other Domain Controllers I can find it fine.  Note that we have a mixed Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 domain at present.

I've run repadmin /showrepl and this is showing a bunch of recent (i.e. today) successes except against one other remote domain controller.

How can I further troubleshoot the failure to replicate this GPO to this particular Domain Controller?

Answer (score 2):

FRS file replication is separate from AD replication.  Typically this means that FRS is jacked up and restarting it on the DC's that are missing the files/folders will replicate.

There is an FRS event log - you can start by investigating any messages there.

There is a command-line tool, ntfrsutl, that can provide some information and is sometimes helpful in forcing a replication:

https://blogs.technet.com/b/justinturner/archive/2007/04/27/quick-tip-force-frs-replication.aspx

```
ntfrsutl forcerepl [computer] /r SetName /p PartnerDnsName
```

E.g.

```
ntfrsutl forcerepl contosodc1 /r "domain system volume (sysvol share)" /p ContosoDC2.Contoso.com
```